# default value f:textarea

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, jstl

I've a probelm with my JSP. I need to set a default value to a f:textarea field so, for that, on my MVC Controller I extract data from DB and on my JPS I print it:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="10" cols="74">
<c:out value="${fn:trim(f_default_text)}" />
</textarea>
```

it works fine and my field is filled but, there are some empty char at the beginning of inserted text. I take a look on DB and the value is correct and I tried to print the value on MVC Controller and it's without empty space.

What's happening?

Many thanks guys!
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `<textarea>` value is picking up the indentation and line separator between the tags.

Try joining the tags like this (`><`):

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="10" cols="74"><c:out
value="${fn:trim(f_default_text)}" /></textarea>
```